# how to create a google sign in button in angular

Tags: html, angular, google-signin

My HTML code in which I want to create a button google sign in and placed it in the middle of the page. I'm using angular and this is the code of `login.component.html`

```
<button class="btn btn-block google-sign-in" border:none; width:110px; height:40px; border-radius:3% (click)="signInHandler()">
      <img [src]="'assets/images/google.svg'" alt="google"/>
      <span>Continue with Google</span>
    </button>
```

but it doesn't work

Comment: Not enough here.. show the component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by `@Mr.Kumar`, there is a lot available for what you want to achieve. I recommend trying the `angularx-social-login` plugin. It allows you to make use of various SDK's (once logged in) by Google, Facebook, Amazon, Microsoft and VK.

Run `npm i angularx-social-login`.

View a demo: https://abacritt.github.io/angularx-social-login/

NPM Page: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angularx-social-login